# Calculating Reclassify Range from Raster

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, reclassify, arcgis-10.5

I am trying to calculate raster reclassify range based on min/max values that are split in equal areas and build up the container for arcpy reclassify.

I am using ArcGIS 10.5.

So far, I've hit an error that says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Erick\Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\PythonProject\Rasterized.py", line 25, in <module>
    elevMinInital2.append(RasterRange)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Output should look like based on min value of 0 and max value of 25 as extracted from a raster (the values will change depends on raster):

rasterRange = "[[0,5,1],[5,10,2],[10,15,3],[15,20,4],[20,25,5]]"

This is my code:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
from arcpy.sa import *

inRaster1 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

elevMINResult = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(inRaster1, "MINIMUM")  
elevMAXResult = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(inRaster1, "MAXIMUM")  

elevMin = float(elevMINResult.getOutput(0))  
elevMax = float(elevMAXResult.getOutput(0))  

divideValue = (elevMax - elevMin)  

RasterRange = []

divideNumber = 5
TempDivideNumber = 4
elevMinAdd = INT(divideValue / divideNumber)

elevMinInital = elevMin + elevMinAdd
elevMinInital2 = ("[{}, {}, 1]".format(elevMin, elevMinInital))
elevMinMin = elevMinInital

elevMinInital2.append(RasterRange)

while divide in TempDivideNumber:
    if divide == 1:
        print "Do nothing"
    else:
        elevMinTemp = elevMinMin
        elevMinMin = elevMinMin + elevMinAdd
        elevText = "[{},{},{}]",format(elevMinMinTemp, elevMinMin, divide)
        elevText.append(RasterRange)

elevFinal = "[{},{},5]".format(elevMinMin, elevMax)
elevFinal.append(RasterRange)
```

Comment: What is your question?  What happens when you run your script?  Are you getting an error, or not the expected output, or no output at all?  Please [edit] your question to include detail about the problem you have, any errors you are getting, and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error on this line

```
elevMinInital2.append(RasterRange)
```

The error says `'str' object has no attribute 'append'`.  This is because you have a string variable that looks something like

```
"[1.0, 0.0, 1]"
```

rather than a List (which you *can* append to) which would look like

```
[1.0, 0.0, 1]
```

You need to change the creation of your `elevMinInital2` variable to be a list rather than a string.  Try this instead:

```
elevMinInital2 = [elevMin, elevMinInital, 1]
```

You can refer to existing variables directly inside lists, you don't need to construct them using string formatting.  Using the above will allow you to append to the list:

```
elevMinInital2.append(RasterRange)
```

You will have the same problem with `elevText` and `elevFinal.  Again, create them as lists rather than strings.

```
elevText = [elevMinMinTemp, elevMinMin, divide]
elevText.append(RasterRange)
```

and

```
elevFinal = [elevMinMin, elevMax, 5]
elevFinal.append(RasterRange)
```

---

That all said, based on your comment at the start of your question that you're expecting something like

```
rasterRange = [[0,5,1],[5,10,2],[10,15,3],[15,20,4],[20,25,5]]
```

You may want to switch your append around, to something like

```
RasterRange.append(elevMinInital2)

RasterRange.append(elevText)

RasterRange.append(elevFinal)
```

Comment: Thank you!  I made the necessary changes and noticed that the python is now saying that:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Erick\Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\PythonProject\Rasterized.py", line 27, in <module>
    for divide in TempDivideNumber:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Failed to execute (Rasterize).

Comment: @ASL_GIS You can't iterate an interger.  You probably want to change it to something like `for divide in range(1, TempDivideNumber):`.  And if you want to include the max `TempDivideNumber` you either need to increase the number by 1 or make it `for divide in range(1, TempDivideNumber + 1):`.  That said, I'm unsure what you're actually trying to do here, so if you don't want to loop through a range of numbers you'll need to provide more info about what you're trying to do. If that is the case, I suggest you ask a new question with your updated code snippet and your new error message.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone.  The solution is below:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
from arcpy.sa import *

inRaster1 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

elevMINResult = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(inRaster1, "MINIMUM")  
elevMAXResult = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(inRaster1, "MAXIMUM")  

elevMin = float(elevMINResult.getOutput(0))  
elevMax = float(elevMAXResult.getOutput(0))  

divideValue = (elevMax - elevMin)  

RasterRange = []

divideNumber = 5
TempDivideNumber = 4
elevMinAdd = int(divideValue / divideNumber)

elevMinInital = elevMin + elevMinAdd
elevMinInital2 = [elevMin, elevMinInital, 1]
elevMinMin = elevMinInital

RasterRange.append(elevMinInital2)

for divide in range(2, TempDivideNumber):
    divide += 1
    elevMinTemp = elevMinMin
    elevMinMin = elevMinMin + elevMinAdd
    elevText = [elevMinTemp, elevMinMin, divide]
    RasterRange.append(elevText)

elevFinal = [elevMinMin, elevMax, 5]
RasterRange.append(elevFinal)

arcpy.AddMessage("Collected the following info: {}".format(RasterRange))
```